# MAGENTO SIDEBAR BLOCK NOT SHOW

Tags: magento, block, show

I had a three block on my left sidebar.
when I am calling this three block as shown below, it shows only last block. First and second blocks are  not showing

```
<reference name="left">
    <remove name="catalog.leftnav" />
    <block type="catalog/navigation" before="-"name="left-nav-brand" template="catalog/product/brand_sidebar.phtml"></block>
    <block type="cms/block" name="left-nav">
         <action method="setBlockId">
             <block_id>left-nav</block_id>
         </action>
    </block>
    <block type="catalog/product_list" name="catalog.product.latest" template="catalog/product/latest.phtml"></block>
</reference>
```

What would be the possible cause ?

Comment: I see no space between `before="-"name="left-nav-brand"`

Comment: all three blocks you have included will render automatically. In first one I can see, no space between `before` and `name`.  ie `before="-"name="left-nav-brand"`. Add a space in between. Ensure that you have a Cms page in admin side which have an id `left-nav`

Comment: i am also include the space  but the problem is not solved

Comment: when you call <remove name="">, there's no way of adding the block back in with the same name. Perhap check if you have <remove name="left-nav"> somewhere?